# how do i pass arguments to generic handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, file-upload, generic-handler

**how do i pass arguments to generic handler (Asp.net) from javascript/jquery?**

i have a generic Handler for `jquery plugin` (`ajaxfileupload`) and i need to pass some arguments from page(jquery/javascript)
   (Ex. Dynamic Save Path , `autogenerated filename`,etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its Working as follow:

```
$.ajaxFileUpload(
{       
    url: 'MyHandler.ashx?filename=test.png&path=../test/Images'
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { name: 'logan', id: 'id' },
        success: function(data, status) {
            if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                if (data.error != '') {
                    alert(data.error);
                } else {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(data, status, e) {
        alert(e);
    }
})
```

In The Generic Handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string stringParam = (string)context.Request["filename"];
}
```

**Another Solution**

```
var strFileName="test.png";
$.ajaxFileUpload(    
{       
    url: 'MyHandler.ashx?filename=test.png&path=../test/Images'
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { name: 'logan', id: 'id',filename: strFileName },
        success: function(data, status) {
            if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                if (data.error != '') {
                    alert(data.error);

                } else {
                alert(data.msg);

                }
            }
        },
        error: function(data, status, e) {
        alert(e);
    }
})
```